# HQL Query - issue in where clause by using alias name

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I got a exception in my where clause. I have the following HQL-Query:

```
SELECT  a.addressType as  myowncolumn
FROM Address a
WHERE myowncolumn = 1
```

I got the following error message: 
**Unknown column "myowncolumn" in where clause**

If I remove the where clause the query is valid.
What´s wrong?

Could you help me, please.

Comment: Please show class of Address entity.

Comment: This class has only postalCode and city and addressType.... it is not a huge class… I have no column like myowncolumn. In the real world I would like to calculate something in the select statement. But before that I have to solve this issue for the alias name.... In read also that the WHERE clause is the first step in the SQL query which will be validate. After that the select clause. But the where clause cannot find any "myowncolumn"

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work even in plain SQL, and you are right in your comment that SQL is validated from inside out / right to left. That's why `myowncolumn` isn't recognized.

Comment: than I got "could not resolve property: myown column of Address"

Comment: This query is OK, works fine for me on Hibernate 4. Can you post the full code, how you are calling it?

Comment: After your edit, my answer didn't stand anymore. I've edited it completely.

Comment: Is there any solution? I try it also with HAVING. But I can´t use HAVING in HQL? I got in this case also an error??

Comment: `HAVING` must be preceded by `GROUP BY`, you can't just put it in place of `WHERE`. I've been trying to make this work but without success. If there is a solution, I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Your entity "must know" (have the links through fields) about myowncolumn. For example, if Address has reference to City and them to Country, then this hql query will be correct:

```
select adr from Address a where a.city.country.name='UK';
```